# Using exported Google Play statistics in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have exported data from Google Play statistics, but I got this:

```
date,total_user_installs
20140618,291
20140617,291
20140616,291
20140615,290
20140614,289
20140613,289
20140612,288
20140611,286
...
...
```

And I want to make some graph from it, but I don't know why, because dates and total installs are merged in one cell which makes it difficult to divide them. So the question is, how to make graph of total installs on each day from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append or change the extension of the file containing that data to `.csv`. You can import it into Excel (read [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx)). Just open it and Excel may prompt you to select data delimiter if it hasn't automatically detected commas as separators.

I'm not a Microsoft Office user so I'll show you how to do it in LibreOffice (similar).

This is the dialog that appears when opening a `csv` file:

[image]

The data has been imported, but the `date` field is recognized as number not as Date/Time. But that shouldn't affect you too much because this format still maintains chronological order. Here is the resulting graph:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly Excel 2010 does not start this wizard when I open CSV file. I managed to import it as external text source from Data tab.